# imap: decode file name from attachment

Tags: php, imap

How to decode file name from attachement in email?

If the filename contains special charactors it looks something like this..

```
ISO-8859-1''%56%61%72%65%6B%F8%62%20%45%55%20%2D%20%4D%61%78
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**rawurldecode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) — decode URL-encoded strings:

```
$string = "ISO-8859-1''%56%61%72%65%6B%F8%62%20%45%55%20%2D%20%4D%61%78";
echo $str = rawurldecode($string); // ISO-8859-1''Varekøb EU - Max
```

Info: returns a string in which the sequences with percent (%) signs followed by two hex digits have been replaced with literal characters. ([RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html))

If the string has spaces in it, use `urldecode()`, however it can be [less safe](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Its a url encoded string:

```
$string = "ISO-8859-1''%56%61%72%65%6B%F8%62%20%45%55%20%2D%20%4D%61%78";
$string = urldecode($string); // obviously use urldecode
$string = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'utf-8', $string);
$string = str_replace('ISO-8859-1', '', $string);
echo $string; // ''Varekøb EU - Max
```

Answer (score 0):

With PHP:

```
echo urldecode('%56%61%72%65%6B%F8%62%20%45%55%20%2D%20%4D%61%78');
```

Output : Varekøb EU - Max